# Is there a way to suggest how a page should be printed in HTML5?

Tags: css, html, printing, media-queries

I'm using an HTML5 presentation tool, and need to output PDF.

I was wondering if there was a way to 'hint' a page with printing suggestions, eg:

- Where page breaks occur
- Tell the page to print in landscape or portrait

etc. **I'm aware that print media queries exist**, but I'm not sure how they can solve these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

and

```
@page {size: landscape}
```

You can find more details: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#propdef-page)

---

Note:
Make sure your HTML is correct and clean. By experience small things like:

```
<table>
   <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Value 1</td><td>Value 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

make cause the strange behaviors on some browsers, but this works better:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>Value 1</td><td>Value 2</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow. Comprehensive answers to both questions and a link to the proper docs. You are a gentleman and a scholar!

Comment: :) Note: I know this is not your question, but you cannot trust that the browser will follow your HTML/CSS (think old browsers, incompatibilities), so you may want to create a button on your page that will print your PDF in the same manner, whatever the browser is and even if they don't have a PDF printer.

Comment: Ack. In my case I'll just link to a working PDF I've produced with a modern browser, after making the print styling changes suggested.